# In Concrete Class my ObjectOutputStream not work not showing correct Result

Tags: java, oop, file-handling, serializable, objectoutputstream

My User Abstract class

```
package mainpkg;

abstract public class User {
    public int id;            
    public String name, email, mobile;     

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String email, String mobile) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    abstract public void setInfo();       
    abstract public void showInfo(); 
}
```

And This is my Student Concreate Class

```
package mainpkg;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student extends User implements Serializable  {
    private float cgpa;
    private String dept;


    public Student(float cgpa, String dept, int id, String name, String email, String mobile) {
        super(id, name, email, mobile);
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInfo() {
        System.out.println("Set Student Info");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter ID: "); id = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Name: "); name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Email: "); email = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Mobile: "); mobile = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter dept: "); dept = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter CGPA: "); cgpa = s.nextFloat();
    }

    @Override
    public void showInfo() {
        display();
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("ID : "+id+", Name : "+name+", email : "+email+", mobile : "+mobile+", CGPA : "+cgpa+", dept : "+dept+";");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID : "+id+", Name : "+name+", email : "+email+", mobile : "+mobile+", CGPA : "+cgpa+", dept : "+dept+";\n";
        }
}
```

This is the code, What show me, My result

```
@FXML
    private void showStudentButtonOnclick(ActionEvent event) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
             File f = new File("student.bin");
            if(!f.exists())
                outputTextFeild.setText("File Does Not Exists!!");

            else {
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                outputTextFeild.setText("");

            try{
//                    Student s;
                    while(true){
                       Student s = (Student) ois.readObject();
                        System.out.println(s.toString());
                        outputTextFeild.appendText(s.toString());
                    }
            } catch (Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(FXMLMainSceneController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        finally{
            if(ois != null)
            try{
                 ois.close();
            } catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        }

    }
```

But This is actully it returns

ID : 0, Name : null, email : null, mobile : null, CGPA : 2.6, dept : cse;

ID : 0, Name : null, email : null, mobile : null, CGPA : 2.7, dept : bba;

They cannt return my super class data.
Pls help me. Thank You.

Comment: Are you writing anything to the File before you read form it?

Comment: Yes I Write. This Was done well. my CGPA : 2.6, dept : cse; come from their correctly.

Comment: Can you post the code where you write to the file and where your file resides in the project directory